# Looking through a string but avoiding substring

Tags: string, replace, substring

I need to check if a string appear in a text. I want to avoid substring.

```
string = "one"
text = "bees make honey

if string in text
```

This return True of course. How do i avoid this issue?

Comment: consider using word boundaries in a regular expression : [wordboundary](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary)

Answer (score 0):

Well, "one" *does* appear in "bees make honey", as a substring.

But if you want to see if "one" is a **word** or not, you can use the `split()`  function.
By words, I mean bees, make, and honey.

Sample python implementation:

```
l = parentString.split(' ') # Returns ['bees','make','honey']
if childString in l:
  print('Word found in parent text')
else:
  print('Word not found in parent text')
```